# Consequence of open mapping theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

The open mapping theorem in complex analysis states that the image of an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is open under a holomorphic mapping.

Does this imply that both the images of the real and imaginary parts of the holomorphic mapping are open?

Comment: First paragraph: There are hypotheses missing. Please put them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it doesn't, because the real and imaginary part independently are not holomorphic, as they do not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Their sum is holomorphic.

This should be pretty clear, because the real part will map into a subset of the real line, and likewise for the imaginary part. These are clearly not open sets - every point is a boundary point, not an interior point.

Comment: I believe the question is whether the images of the real and imaginary parts will be open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In that case the answer is yes isn't it? The topology on $\mathbb{C}$ is just the product topology of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$, right?